# javascript dynamically changing content of a web page with nested for loops

Tags: javascript, dom

simply put i want to change all the values in headings to 't' when a button is pressed so i have the following code there are no errors 
what i expect to happen is for all headings to change their content to 't'

```js
window.onload = function () {
  let specialButton = document.getElementById('mainButton')

  specialButton.addEventListener('click', removeHeadings())

  function removeHeadings () {
    for (var j = 1, length = 7; j < length; j++) {
      let headings = document.getElementsByName('h' + j)
      for (var i = 0, len = headings.length; i < len; i++) {
        headings[i].innerHTML = 't '
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>s</h1>
<h2>s</h2>
<h3>s</h3>
<button id="mainButton">Remove Headings</button>
```

also please tell me why the above does not work

Comment: You want `getElementsByTagName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are executing the `removeHeadings` function and passing it as the argument for the event listener. Secondly, you are trying to get elements by name when you mean to get them by their tag name – to do this use `getElementsByTagName`.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  let specialButton = document.getElementById('mainButton')

  specialButton.addEventListener('click', removeHeadings)

  function removeHeadings () {
    for (var j = 1, length = 7; j < length; j++) {
      let headings = document.getElementsByTagName('h' + j)
      for (var i = 0, len = headings.length; i < len; i++) {
        headings[i].innerHTML = 't '
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>s</h1>
<h2>s</h2>
<h3>s</h3>
<button id="mainButton">Remove Headings</button>
```

Comment: whats the difference between getElementsByTagName and getElementsByName

Comment: Firstly, you are executing the removeHeadings function and passing it as the argument for the event listener. can you please clarify more

Comment: @TheLinuxPro The first one finds by Html TAGs and the second by the attribute `name` of elements.

Comment: whats the difference between an html TAG and a name of an element isn't the name of the html element its tag

Answer (score 1):

You're suddenly calling the function `removeHeadings()`, you need to pass the function and not the result of calling it.

```
specialButton.addEventListener('click', removeHeadings()); // Remove the parentheses
                                                      ^^
```

Further, you need to use the function `getElementsByTagName`.

```
let headings = document.getElementsByName('h' + j)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The function `getElementsByName` finds elements by the attribute `name` in elements. for Example:

```
<input type='button' name='myButton'>
                     ^^^^
```

The function `getElementsByTagName` finds elements by the HTML tag, in your case the `H` tags, for example:

```
<input type='button' name='myButton'>
 ^^^^^
```

Comment: i am having difficulty understanding what you just said can you elaborate further

Comment: i know i am bombarding you with questions but what do the parenthesis do whats the difference isn't the end result the same

Comment: @TheLinuxPro no, because you're calling the function and not passing it as a handler instead.  What you're actually doing is passing `undefined` which is the result of calling `removeHeadings`.

Answer (score 0):

By Using jQuery you can do this like.

**HTML**

```
<h1>S</h1>
<h2>S</h2>
<h3>S</h3>
<h4>S</h4>
<h5>S</h5>
<h6>S</h6>
<button id="change">CHANGE</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#change").click(function change() {
    console.log("CLICKED");
    $("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6").html("T");
});
```

[JsFiddle Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/5jyz9ohx/8/)

Comment: isn't jquery redundant with most of the features of newer versions of javascript integrating jquery in?